# how to find out the general response speed of elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

how to check the general *response speed* of elastic search.We have two elastic search in two different environment but in one environment we can process more records with less time interval as comapre to other one.for comparing two elastic search i need the response speed.Any suggestion on this.

Comment: What do you mean by general response speed? You can see the query performance with the help of profile api. Or else you could use something like Jmeter to check the rest response time. Elastic search also has a more comprehensive benchmarking tool Rally

Comment: @adityasinghraghav localhost:9200/_stats i.e Indices Stats from this we can figured it out statistics on different operations happening on an index.

Answer (score 0):

You can always install [Marvel](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/marvel) on your Elasticsearch nodes and monitor their performance from there:

> Marvel helps you keep a pulse on the state of your Elasticsearch deployment. As a window into your cluster, Marvel is a tool for optimizing your Elasticsearch performance and diagnosing issues quickly.

Marvel used to be a paid product, but is now free to use in combination with a (free) basic license.

Hope this helps :)